# Can't uninstall Angular CLI version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have been trying to create a new project in Angular6 using the latest CLI, but have been unable to update. In an attempt to resolve, I have been simply trying to remove Angular CLI and start over but even that's not working!

From a random folder (without a project in it), if I run `ng -v` I get

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.4
Node: 9.4.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular:
...
```

So easily enough I try to run the following commands;

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
```

Then another `ng -v`, which I would expect it to complain that ng was not found, instead shows the same thing!

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.4
Node: 9.4.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular:
...
```

I was thinking this could be related to the fact that I use NVM to manage my Node version, but I haven't been able to find anything.

I have also tried `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` after all the above, but when I check my ng version it still shows the same 1.5.4 instead of the latest version.

Some info;

1. I'm not even in a project directory so there's no node_modules and everything is global -g
2. I'm on OSX and using NVM to manage my Node versions, from the context of this I'm running node 9.4.0

@Everett pointed out a suggestion to delete any local references. I found that `/Users/joshua/.nvm/versions/node` stores extra node_modules directories. My problem persists though...

In the folder for `/Users/joshua/.nvm/versions/node/**v9.4.0**/lib/node_modules` I do not see any references to angular; however...

In `/Users/joshua/.nvm/versions/node/**v6.11.5**/lib/node_modules` I see folder `@angular/cli`

My thought here would be that if I were using node nvm version v9.4.0, which I am, is that it would be using that node's version of angular. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case. I am hesitant to delete @angular refs from my other directories as I'm in the middle of other projects and don't want to break my environment right now, though I'm sure a full Node and NVM delete would resolve my issue.

Comment: try  `npm cache clean` instead of `npm cache verify`

Comment: @Vikas `npm cache clean` was phased out > v5, this command produces an error

Answer (score 1):

I have version 6.0.1 installed. The steps you went through to uninstall did not work for me too.

So, go into you roaming folder and find npm and manually delete angular >> angular-cli

Angular was located at this path for me:

```
C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

Delete the angular folder and/or the angualr-cli folder

It seems like the old file structure is different from what it is today.

I then reinstalled using:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

and am now on:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...
```

Comment: I'm not even in a project directory, so there is no node_modules folder, and everything is global -g

Comment: Hrmm so I'm on OSX and using nvm to manage my node version. For the active node version I removed @angular/cli and ng from everywhere... but apparently it's still present in other version. Maybe the way something is accessing it globally doesn't like different angular-cli versions across Node/NVM versions :-\ ---- I think I will just have to clear out everything and from from a clean Node/NVM environment

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x

Comment: Good idea to try, not quite, I updated my answer with the info

Comment: this solution worked for me. I experienced exactly as the OP. npm install/uninstall/verify didn't work. I was trying to upgrade from cli 9.1.7 to 9.1.9. So, in the end, I have to delete everything under Roaming/npm/ and Roaming/npm-cache. Then do the npm install cli command, and it worked cleanly. Hope this helps someone.